# Plotting gaps in time series as zeroes in R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2 is interpolating the missing measurements in the data. How to make it plot them as zeroes? Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

x = c(1, 3, 5)  # The time axis
y = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.9)  # The measurements

ggplot(data.frame(x, y), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line() +
    ylim(0, 1)
```

Output:

[image: Interpolated line]

Desired Output:

[image: Desired line]

Comment: If you want `ggplot` to plot a particular point, you have to tell it. How would it know what points you think are missing? You have to make `x` a vector containing all the time points at which you want to record a value, and `y` a vector containing all the values.

Comment: I don't want to touch the data, but I know these are better considered zeroes from the business perspective. `ggplot` is already assuming false values of the missing `y`s without any indication and such a default behaviour is illusive, that's why I wanted to change that default behaviour if possible. Shouldn't it not plot anything instead?

Comment: Jabro but that's what a line plot is. It joins definite data points with extrapolating lines. If you don't want these lines you draw points instead. If you had a value for 1, 2, and 3, you could use your logic to argue that since you don't have a point for 2.5 or 1.67 or 1.00001 there should be a zero there too. In your particular domain zeros might make sense as a stand in for missing values, but that's not generally true. Does the value of all stocks drop to 0 on a Sunday when there's no trading?

Comment: I assume you mean interpolating lines, and I totally get your point, thank you. I was hoping for more "flexibility" to fit the particularity of my domain with discrete `x`.

Comment: @AllanCameron After other answers I guess your comment is the best answer, which means this particular behaviour has to be dealt with at the data level and not the visualisation's because it is not generalisable with line plots. If you like to post that as an answer I will accept it, because it directly addresses the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @AllanCameron comments, the issue needs to be resolved on the **data level** and not on the visualisation level. For that reason, the records which hold zero measurements must be manually and explicitly appended to the data or else they will be interpolated.

There is no way to make `ggplot`'s `geom_line` show a zero where a record does not exist in the data even with a discrete `x-axis`, and while this makes sense for certain applications, it is not generalisable.

Answer (score 3):

**1) zoo** Create a zoo object with frequency 1, convert that to ts class and back to zoo.  Fill in the generated NAs with 0 and plot.  (Add any desired geoms onto the end of the autoplot line using + as usual.)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

z <- na.fill(as.zoo(as.ts(zoo(y, x, frequency = 1))), 0)
autoplot(z)
```

[image: screenshot]

**2) merge**  Expand x and merge it with the original data.  Then fill in the NAs with 0.

```
xx <- seq(min(x), max(x))
m <- merge(data.frame(x, y), data.frame(x = xx), all = TRUE)
m[is.na(m)] <- 0
ggplot(m, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Eventually it has to be dealt with at the data level then

Answer (score 0):

Analogous to G. Grothendieck second solution but using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
m <- df[list(x = seq(min(x), max(x))), on = "x"][, y := nafill(y, fill = 0)]
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 3, 5), 
  y = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.9)
)
```